# Manipulando datas com PHP

Tags: php

Preciso subtrair uma data de outra e mostrar o resultado disso. Porém o resultado as vezes não é o correto.

Por exemplo:

Eu subtraio a data 2018-07-27 16:53 por 2018-07-27 16:51, o resultado seria 2 minutos, né? Mas, o PHP me retorna 31 dias, 21 horas e 2 minutos.

O código está assim:

```
// $inicio vem do BD no formato YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS
            $inicio = $dado_temp['inicio'];
            $tempo_decorrido = time()-strtotime($inicio);
                ?>
                    <p class="termina"><?php echo date("j", $tempo_decorrido)."d ".date("H", $tempo_decorrido)."h ".date("i", $tempo_decorrido)."min" ;?></p>

         // Ele deveria me retornar 0d 0h 02min, mas ele me retorna 31d 21h 02min. Se eu subtrair datas com um intervalo de tempo maior ele me retorna corretamente.
```

Comment: Vitor, achei uma explicação da função "date_diff" na documentação do php aqui: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)

Comment: Legal Rodrigo. Eu fiz a diferença, porém o retorno é um objeto array. Como eu o manipulo?

Comment: Você pode fazer assim:
`$diff = date_diff($data1, $data2);`
`echo 'Ano:' . $diff->y;`
Para pegar o ano. Use "m" para o mês, "d" para o dia, "h" para hora, "i" para minuto e "s" para os segundos.

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo, funcionou perfeitamente. :)